# how to pass id from get method to post method in springs mvc?

Tags: spring-mvc

My Controller:

```
       @RequestMapping(value = "/BankEdit", method = RequestMethod.GET) public ModelAndView BankEdit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,BankBean bankBean) 
        {       
        ModelAndView model= null;
        model = new ModelAndView("accounts/company/manage_bank_edit");  
        long bName=Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("bName"));
        System.out.println("Banme get "+request.getParameter("bName"));


        return model;
        }
```

am getting bName value in get method...I need the same value in post method..getting null value

POst Method:

```
      @RequestMapping(value = "/BankEdit", method = RequestMethod.POST) public ModelAndView BankEditPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,BankBean bankBean) throws Exception
        {       
        ModelAndView model= null;
        model = new ModelAndView("accounts/company/manage_bank");
        long session_id=(Long) request.getSession().getAttribute("sessionId");
         long sessionBId=(Long) request.getSession().getAttribute("sessionBId");

         System.out.println("B_name==="+request.getParameter("bName"));

         long bName=Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("bName"));

            bankBean = accDao.editBank(bankBean,sessionBId,session_id,bName);


        return model;
        }
```

Comment: Did you send `bName` in post body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In post method you try to retrieve parameter value `bName`. as like `get` method.

For `GET` request value will be send as parameter like

```
~/BankEdit?name1=value1&name2=value2
```

so `request.getParameter("bName")` you get that value.

For `POST` method value send via message body not send in parameter so you got null `request.getParameter("bName"))` cause you try to extract from parameter request url.

For received `POST` value you need declare parameter object on method argument and you got the value from message body.

If `bName` is part of your `BankBean` then you retrieve from your `BankBean.bName` object.

If not then declare in your method argument and get your value.

If bName is object of `BankBean`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/BankEdit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView BankEditPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,BankBean bankBean) throws Exception{       
    ModelAndView model= null;
    model = new ModelAndView("accounts/company/manage_bank");
    long session_id=(Long) request.getSession().getAttribute("sessionId");
    long sessionBId=(Long) request.getSession().getAttribute("sessionBId");

    System.out.println("B_name=== "+bankBean.bName);

    long bName=Long.parseLong(bankBean.bName);

    bankBean = accDao.editBank(bankBean,sessionBId,session_id,bName);
        
    return model;
}
```

In other way received string:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/BankEdit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView BankEditPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,BankBean bankBean, String stringValue) throws Exception{       
    ModelAndView model= null;
    model = new ModelAndView("accounts/company/manage_bank");
    long session_id=(Long) request.getSession().getAttribute("sessionId");
    long sessionBId=(Long) request.getSession().getAttribute("sessionBId");

    System.out.println("B_name=== "+stringValue);

    long bName=Long.parseLong(stringValue);

    bankBean = accDao.editBank(bankBean,sessionBId,session_id,bName);
        
    return model;
}
```